# ubuntu 19.10 stuck on loading screen on acer aspire 5750

Tags: boot, intel-graphics, intel, 19.10, acer

Does anyone know why Ubuntu 19.10 occasionally gets stuck on the loading screen? Ubuntu is installed as the only operating system on the laptop and the only modifications that were made to it is that I installed the Chromium web browser (snap) and GParted. I have also installed the latest updates via Software Updater.

Laptop specs:

- Acer Aspire 5750-6456
- Intel Core i5-2450M
- Intel HD graphics 3000
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- 500GB HDD

Results of `free -h` :

[image]

SMART data:

[image]

Comment: Does it get to the point of showing the Ubuntu logo with the rotating dots? And, if so, can you hit the ESC key to see more details?

Comment: Yes, and the escape key does nothing. Furthermore, there is no hard drive activity (laptop has hard drive indicator lights). The only way to fix it is to force power off the laptop and turn on and it solves the issue for ~3-5 startups before being stuck on the loading screen again. This issue has persisted since ~2012 when I first started using Ubuntu.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app SMART Data & Tests window.

Comment: Also show me `grep -i wayland /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WRzxWuc.png https://i.imgur.com/6mmI3U2.png

Comment: Thank you for the info. We're missing screenshot #2 of the scrollable SMART Data window. Also please show me a screenshot of `gparted`. Also show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Then I can make some recommendations.

Comment: Also, please start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them. Thanks.

Comment: Please also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Thanks.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Two things that happened to me:

1. Replace the swap file, it's in the root.

Use these commands to do this:

```
swapon --show
sudo swapoff -a /swapfile
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
swapon --show
```

I am happy to report that ubuntu has not frozen once since I did this.

2. Dual boot issue between Windows and Ubuntu partitions:

When switching from ubuntu to Windows, a normal restart works.
When switching from Windows to ubuntu, only Shutdown and power on works.

Perhaps your disk once had a Windows partition on it? If so, find out if you can get rid of it, and it might help the grub program to sort things out.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, ubuntu 19.10 is the only installed OS on the laptop.

Comment: Without asking, how do you know the user has /swapfile vs swap partition? User doesn't have Windows. GRUB has nothing to do with Windows. dd should be used to create swap files, not fallocate. /etc/fstab would require an edit. Swap is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Wayland**

Disable Wayland problem on boot screen...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

and change...

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to...

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

---

**BIOS**

Note: BEFORE updating the BIOS, backup all of your important files.

Note: Current version is 1.21. https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3474?b=1

---

**Swap**

For 4G RAM, your current 2G swap is too small. We need to enlarge it.

More details coming...

---

**Bad Blocking**

Your HDD has read errors and bad blocks. We need to bad block your hard disk.

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this may take a few hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
         read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
         inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
         running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```